# Get count of true values in JSON with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object like this:

```
filters: {
        module: {
            value: "All",
            active: false
        },
        dates: {
            value: [],
            active: true
        }
    }
```

How to count active filters, based on this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reduce` to iterate over the `values` of each object, extract the `active` property from each, and add that boolean to the accumulator, which will coerce it to a number:

```js
const obj = {
  filters: {
    module: {
      value: "All",
      active: false
    },
    dates: {
      value: [],
      active: true
    },
    foo: {
      value: "All",
      active: false
    },
    bar: {
      value: [],
      active: true
    }
  }
};

console.log(
  Object.values(obj.filters).reduce((a, { active }) => a + active, 0)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all the keys inside the filters using `Object.keys` which will give an array and then use `reduce` function to count the number of active true

```js
let someObj = {
  filters: {
    module: {
      value: "All",
      active: false
    },
    dates: {
      value: [],
      active: true
    }
  }

};

let count = Object.keys(someObj.filters).reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (someObj.filters[curr].active === true) {
    acc += 1;
  }
  return acc;
}, 0);

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `filter()`

```js
var filters = {
        module: {
            value: "All",
            active: false
        },
        dates: {
            value: [],
            active: true
        }
    }
    
var active = Object.keys(filters).filter(k => filters[k].active);

console.log(active.length)
```

Comment: One line: `Object.keys(filters).filter(k => filters[k].active)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
var filters = {
  module: {
    value: "All",
    active: false
  },
  dates: {
    value: [],
    active: true
  }
};

console.log(Object.values(filters).filter(element => element.active === true).length)
```

Hope this helps !